# overflow:hidden doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm having trouble with overflow:hidden.
I have 2 logos at the top of my page, with a trapezium underlying it.
I basically made 2 parallelograms and used `transform: skewX()` to make it tilt at an angle, then `overflow:hidden` to make sure the sides don't show up.

My point of view of this can be seen here: [http://imgur.com/a/cAUUj](https://imgur.com/a/cAUUj)

A live version is available at http://ddlgaming.com/giga/giga2/

Thank you in advance!

My code is as follows:

```css
.clearfix {
  clear: both;
}

body {
  background-color: rgb(21, 14, 43);
  background-image: url("../images/backgroundimage.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  min-height: 100%;
  background-position: center center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#gigalogomainbox {
  float: left;
  width: 30vw;
  height: 10vw;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: skewX(20deg);
  margin: 0 0 0 -4vw;
  background-color: white;
}

#gigalogobox {
  margin: 0 3vw 0 2vw;
  padding: 0 0 0 2vw;
  width: 100%;
  height: 8vw;
}

#gigalogo {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 3vw 2vw 0 0;
  height: 7vw;
}

#steamlogomainbox {
  width: 15vw;
  height: 10vw;
  float: right;
  margin: 0 -4vw 0 0;
  background-color: white;
  /*000c21*/
  transform: skewX(-20deg);
  overflow: hidden;
}

#steamlogobox {
  margin: 0 -2vw 0 3vw;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20%;
}

#steamlogo {
  padding: 0 0 0 2vw;
  margin: 3vw 0vw 0 0;
  transform: skewX(20deg);
  height: 7vw;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Jura" />
</head>

<body>


  <!--Giga logo, top left-->
  <div id="gigalogomainbox" class="clearfix">
    <div id="gigalogobox">
      <img id="gigalogo" src="images/gigalogo.png">
    </div>
  </div>

  <!--Steam logo, top right-->
  <div id="steamlogomainbox">
    <div id="steamlogobox">
      <img id="steamlogo" src="images/steamlogo.png">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `A live version is available at` - has no `overflow:hidden` on body like in your code here - so which overflow is causing you problems?

Comment: you have an `<a>` element as a child of `<ul>` ... `<ul>` should only have `<li>` as child

Comment: sorry guys, I've edited my post to keep things simpler. Basically, I can scroll and the overflow is still visible on the steam logo at the top right. That's my biggest problem bugging me now

Comment: @Mark You can't really skew one side of a div completely although you can hide below container like [this](https://codepen.io/o/pen/wosfH)

Comment: as much as i'm getting, you just want the `skew` to occur on one side? not both left-n-right together?

Comment: Yup that's what I'm hoping for @DeepakYadav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

overflow hidden not going to hide extra white bar in right side.Butter i suggest you use clip-path or use this site for desire look.
http://bennettfeely.com/clippy/

Comment: that seems to work! I'll mess around with it tonight, i'll see if it'll fix my problems. Thank you!